# Swift Firebase snapshot.exists() keeps Value True

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`snapshot.exists()`  is retaining its value of true when `someValue == nil.`

I dont know how to reset the `snapshot.exists()` value after the initial query. How do i set the database call to only be triggered when i call upon it? like removing the observer the proper way?

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()


ref.child("matches").child("available").queryOrdered(byChild: "opponent_1").queryEqual(toValue: potential_oponnent).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in

if (snapshot.exists()) && someValue != nil {

}else {

  ref.removeAllObservers()


}
```

Do i need to use `ref.removeObserver(withHandle: )` or `ref.removeAllObservers()`?

Comment: The `ref.removeAllObservers()` in the code you shared is not needed, since the observer of `observeSingleEvent` is auto-removed once the event fires. Aside from that I'm having a hard time understanding what the problem is. What is the code trying to accomplish, and what is the result of the code when you run it?